# angular typescript dock layout engine

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dock

I'm looking for dock layout engine for angularjs written in typescript. I found [Dockspawn](http://www.dockspawn.com/) but it is written in DART and it's not compatible with the rest of my project. Does somebody know any dock layout engine (even paid ones) for angularjs in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Dockspawn because at runtime DART is JavaScript, so as TypeScript. You just need to find a way to make TypeScript aware of Dockspawn and you can do that using a Type definition file.

The types definition file for Dockspawn [is available online](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/dock-spawn/dock-spawn.d.ts).

You can install this kind of files using a tool known as tsd. You can find a basic example [here](https://bertt.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/typescript-and-jquery-example/).

Comment: I want to ad that dockspawn is incredible buggy. Our QA team found numerous blocking bugs within minutes of using it. It gets real ugly.

If you end up building your own, use CSS percentages instead of trying to generate pixel values for every single action. This was the fix for a lot of bugs that I experienced in my component (as well as the clear cause of bugs that I've seen in other components, like UI-Layout).

Answer (score 2):

I think your real problem is that dockspawn was abandoned. This is something I built at my company (which, sorry, we don't sell software)and it turns out that Angular is the worst thing you could use to build a layout engine like this.

Managing scope chains among components that are constantly changing positions, opening/closing, resizing, and floating is entirely too complicated for this type of project. You will end up with 15 step bug reports everywhere, and unless you have a perfect algorithm set in place before ever developing anything you will end up spending weeks re-writing code.

Solution (and not the one you want to hear): drop it. Web design is meant for developing pages within the browser, not for developing windows with tabs within your browser window which is full of tabs. The control and flexibility is very nice, but there is always a way to provide the user with just as much control by setting up panels on the page in the positions in which they will be consistently used the most.

Sooner or later someone will develop what you are looking for and release it, but it probably won't be in Angular and it's definitely going to cost money.